# Deleting files conditionally in R

Tags: r, filelist

I have time series data as follow:

L1_0101_0601_A
L1_0101_0603_A
L1_0101_0605_B
L1_0101_0608_B
L1_0101_0610_C
L1_0101_0612_C
L1_0101_0615_A
L1_0101_0617_A
L1_0101_0619_A
L1_0101_0622_B
L1_0101_0624_B
L1_0101_0626_C
L1_0101_0629_C
L1_0101_0631_A
L1_0101_0633_A
L1_0101_0635_B
L1_0101_0638_B
L1_0101_0640_C
L1_0101_0642_C
L1_0101_0645_A
L1_0101_0647_A
L1_0101_0649_A

and so on.

[image]

I want to keep the files conditionally. I want to keep only two continuous files ending A, B and C. In the file list, sometimes, there are three continuous files ending A or B or C. At that time, I want to remove the last file.

In this example, I would like to drop "L1_0101_0619_A" and "L1_0101_0649_A" because it is the third files ending A. I will keep other twos. Like this, there are several files which I would like to remove.

Comment: please use `dput()` to share a reproducible example of your data

Comment: I don't know how to list using R. Here is the list:
L1_0101_0601_A
L1_0101_0603_A
L1_0101_0605_B
L1_0101_0608_B
L1_0101_0610_C
L1_0101_0612_C
L1_0101_0615_A
L1_0101_0617_A
L1_0101_0619_A
L1_0101_0622_B
L1_0101_0624_B
L1_0101_0626_C
L1_0101_0629_C

and so on.

Comment: Your input is unclear. Is this a vector, e.g., as returned by `list.files`?

Comment: Assuming that's the case, your first step should be to split the character strings by `_`.

Comment: @Roland, it is the list of files in one folder.